# Filtering the output for importhtml in Google Sheets

Tags: filter, google-sheets

I am building a google sheet to do calculations based on information I found on different websites and stumbled upon the IMPORTHTML function in Google Sheets.
Terrific, I want to import tables and then use some of the values out of those tables to build my sheet and make further calculations.
However, since the function retrieves both the headers and all the information in the table that makes it quite hard to work with. Instead I would like to pull only certain of the data, preferably specific cells in the table pulled.
Is this possible?

For example:

```
=ImportHtml("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_India"; "table";3)
```

returns a huge list, what if I would like to pull only the values of B7 and D7? Is that possible? Even filtering out a single row would be useful, whatever that is more feasible. The most important part is that I can get a single row and dont have the full table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the INDEX function, doing exactly what I need it to do!